# WSO2IS Authenticator is null (simplesamlphp and wso2 samlsso)

Tags: java, wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2IS setup on one server and simplesamlphp setup on another server. There is an application on the simplesamlphp server that I want WSO2IS to provide authentication for. At this point, I have followed the directions on this:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Logging+in+to+SimpleSAMLphp+using+Identity+Server

The only change I have made is the entity ID is samls.

When I go to Test authentication sources in simplesamlphp and click wso2-sp, the request is sent off to WSO2IS and I receive "Error 500 - Internal Server Error".

In the log below you will see that everything seems to be going well up until Request Validation is successful.  After that something goes wrong.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  I have been searching and I'm not coming up with anything.  I feel like I've stopped making progress and I'm not sure where to turn now.

I have DEBUG on for samlsso and I have this in the log for the request:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,339] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : SAMLRequest=fZJRT8IwFIX%2FytL3bWzOAQ2QoMRIgkoAffDFlLs716RrZ28H%2Bu%2FtNk30haempz3fvfe0MxK1aviydZXe4UeL5ILPWmni%2FcGctVZzI0gS16JG4g74fvmw4Wk04o01zoBR7I%2FlskMQoXXSaBasV3P2VpRYlCMsxzApk2Tid3CEMpvmeYGIWQ7THECMUwQWvKAl75wzD%2FJ2ohbXmpzQzkujZBKO0jBNDknOs2t%2Bnb2yYOWnkVq43lU51xCP4zOZNCzwFFVXGl0EpubTLLuKu%2BaJDAuWvz3eGk1tjXaP9iQBn3ebgeIh3q8MCBWR0RKi6qtBC%2B0RQ6WgQ8Yk60Zhx4xrU7QKo6Zq%2BhoxDWsaCqBe7TuihgXbnzxvpC6kfr8c5XG4RPz%2BcNiG26f9gS1mHZj30dhFP9As%2FivNhtd%2B9LD1amuUhK%2FgzthauMu1OkUWYdlf5c4KTRK181kpZc63FoXDOXO2RRYvhpL%2F%2F9TiGw%3D%3D&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Fdevlocal.sonic.hypercube-llc.com%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fauthenticate.php%3Fas%3Dwso2-sp

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,342] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Request message <samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_dfedf0ef7c8f118fedcbcf4966deee46c96cca72ec" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-02-21T16:45:54Z" Destination="https://wso2-dev.h3net.com:9443/samlsso" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://devlocal.sonic.hypercube-llc.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/wso2-sp" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"><saml:Issuer>samls</saml:Issuer><samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/></samlp:AuthnRequest>

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,352] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} -  Authentication Request Validation is successful..

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,399] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} -  Authenticator is null

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,433] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : SAMLRequest=fZJRT8IwFIX%2FytL3bWzOAQ2QoMRIgkoAffDFlLs716RrZ28H%2Bu%2FtNk30haempz3fvfe0MxK1aviydZXe4UeL5ILPWmni%2FcGctVZzI0gS16JG4g74fvmw4Wk04o01zoBR7I%2FlskMQoXXSaBasV3P2VpRYlCMsxzApk2Tid3CEMpvmeYGIWQ7THECMUwQWvKAl75wzD%2FJ2ohbXmpzQzkujZBKO0jBNDknOs2t%2Bnb2yYOWnkVq43lU51xCP4zOZNCzwFFVXGl0EpubTLLuKu%2BaJDAuWvz3eGk1tjXaP9iQBn3ebgeIh3q8MCBWR0RKi6qtBC%2B0RQ6WgQ8Yk60Zhx4xrU7QKo6Zq%2BhoxDWsaCqBe7TuihgXbnzxvpC6kfr8c5XG4RPz%2BcNiG26f9gS1mHZj30dhFP9As%2FivNhtd%2B9LD1amuUhK%2FgzthauMu1OkUWYdlf5c4KTRK181kpZc63FoXDOXO2RRYvhpL%2F%2F9TiGw%3D%3D&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Fdevlocal.sonic.hypercube-llc.com%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fauthenticate.php%3Fas%3Dwso2-sp

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,434] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Cannot find AuthenticationResult from the cache

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,434] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Session data is not found for key : b50b8360-3309-4dab-9c24-4d00da8b945b

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-21 10:44:26,435] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:678)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:96)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1067)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendToFrameworkForAuthentication(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:457)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:361)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:196)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:96)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Decode the SAML message and make sure parameters match - IdP issuer (resident idp entitiy id), sp ACS and Destination url. And that you set n authenticator for the configured SP (you didn't describe the IS configuration of SP)

Comment: The authenticator is where I believe I'm having an issue.  I don't see anything that says how to set the authenticator or where to do it.  I found something that said to update security/authenticators.xml but that broke everything so I undid that.

Comment: The issuer is correct after decoding the SAML message.

Comment: Did you fix this?